# Retention policy on mysite - move / delete after AD user no longer exist

Tags: 2013, site, mysite, retention

I'm new to setting up retention policy on site (mysite). Is there a easy way to move the entire users mysite when the user are removed / deactived from AD? What's the best way of doing this?

If yes, a second question is there a way to email an administrator that a mysite is going to be moved / deleted?

Sharepoint 2013 Enterprise - on-premise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens automatically for you when an account is marked as disabled or deleted. Ownership transfers to the users manager to access any business critical content. If a the user does not have a manager, then it can be transferred to a service account.

Kirk Evans has detailed it in [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2012/06/25/top-recommendations-for-managing-the-my-site-cleanup-timer-job.aspx), it is for 2010 but the same thing is in place for 2013.